# Timestamp from firestore gets converted to a Map when using cloud function

Tags: json, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, google-cloud-functions

So I have a `Timestamp` in cloud firestore. I am using cloud function to retrieve data from firestore to flutter. But `JSON` formats timestamp to map due to which I am not able to use it as timestamp. How to convert it again into timestamp?
This is how I ulpoaded timestamp to firestore.

```dart
var reference = Firestore.instance.collection('posts');
      reference.add({
        'postTitle': this.title,
        'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
        'likes': {},
        'ownerId': userId,
      })
```

To retrieve data this is the code:

```dart
 factory Post.fromJSON(Map data){
    return Post(
      timestamp: data['timestamp'],
    );
  }
```

```dart
List<Post> _generateFeed(List<Map<String, dynamic>> feedData) {
    List<Post> listOfPosts = [];

    for (var postData in feedData) {
      listOfPosts.add(Post.fromJSON(postData));
    }

    return listOfPosts;
  }
```

but this returns an error.

```
I/flutter (17271): The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (17271): _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot>#1536b):
I/flutter (17271): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp'
```

This is my cloud function.
`getFeed.ts`

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const getFeedModule = function(req, res){
    const uid = String(req.query.uid);

    async function compileFeedPost(){
        const following = await getFollowing(uid, res)as any;

        let listOfPosts = await getAllPosts(following, res);

        listOfPosts = [].concat.apply([], listOfPosts);

        res.send(listOfPosts);
    }

    compileFeedPost().then().catch();
}

async function getAllPosts(following, res) {
    let listOfPosts = [];

    for (let user in following){
        listOfPosts.push( await getUserPosts(following[user], res));
    }
    return listOfPosts;
}

function getUserPosts(userId, res){
    const posts = admin.firestore().collection("posts").where("ownerId", "==", userId).orderBy("timestamp")

    return posts.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot){
        let listOfPosts = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
            listOfPosts.push(doc.data());
        });

        return listOfPosts;
    })
}

function getFollowing(uid, res){
    const doc = admin.firestore().doc(`user/${uid}`)
    return doc.get().then(snapshot => {
        const followings = snapshot.data().followings;

        let following_list = [];

        for (const following in followings){
            if (followings[following] === true){
                following_list.push(following);
            }
        }
        return following_list;
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    })
}
```

cloud function `index.ts`

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { getFeedModule } from "./getFeed"
admin.initializeApp();

export const getFeed = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    getFeedModule(req, res);
})
```

invoked by this

```dart
_getFeed() async {
    print("Starting getFeed");
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String userId = user.uid;
    var url =
        'https://us-central1-jaluk-quiz.cloudfunctions.net/getFeed?uid=' + userId;
    var httpClient = HttpClient();

    List<QuizViewer>listOfPosts;
    String result;
    try {
      var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      var response = await request.close(); 
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        String json = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        prefs.setString("feed", json);
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> data =
            jsonDecode(json).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
        listOfPosts = _generateFeed(data);
        result = "Success in http request for feed";
      } else {
        result =
            'Error getting a feed: Http status ${response.statusCode} | userId $userId';
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      result = 'Failed invoking the getFeed function. Exception: $exception';
    }
    print(result);

    setState(() {
      feedData = listOfPosts;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong.  Please edit the question to show all relevant code that's not working the way you expect, including both populating the database, and reading it back out.  Please verify that you've actually stored a timestamp typed object and not something else.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated my question with some codes. I am new to flutter and coding so I don't know which line of code to put in. My whole code is very long.

Comment: You mentioned Cloud Functions.  How is that involved here?  If it's not involved, please simplify your question by removing it.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok, I added the cloud function code just now.

Comment: How is the function involved with your Flutter code?  It doesn't look related to how the app is doing anything, as we can't see how it's being invoked, or what exactly it generates.

Comment: @DougStevenson added the invoked code now.

Comment: The JSON serialized timestamp object generated by your function is always going to show up as an object with seconds and nanoseconds.  You will have to reconstitute that timestamp object on the client.

Comment: Can you please show me how to reconstitute it because I don't know how to do. I'm new to coding.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hey! Good news. I have solved my problem. Thank you so much for giving your time. I appreciate it a lot. And I am a big fan of yours(from Youtube videos).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are dealing with a Timestamp that's been serialized as an object with seconds and nanoseconds components, you can use those components to create a new [Timestamp](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Timestamp-class.html) object with `new Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds)`.

Comment: Wow! that's genius. Thanks for the help guru! But the JSON is giving me in this format {_seconds: 1552543554634, _nanoseconds: 88000000}. How do I put it in Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds)?

Comment: I don't actually do dart programming.  You will have to figure out how to get those values out of your Cloud Functions response.  It should be straightforward, if you are already accessing other parts of the response.

Comment: Oh ok, no problem! You showed me the way. I will try to put it in the timestamp. Thanks again!

Comment: @DougStevenson anyway to avoid this serialization from cloudfunction  ? It's not conveniant to parse each JSON TIMESTAMP each time I return an object with timestamp from cloudfunction

Answer (score 9):

You can use converted to receive DateTime like this:

```
class TimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime, dynamic> {
  const TimestampConverter();

  @override
  DateTime fromJson(dynamic data) {
    Timestamp timestamp;
    if (data is Timestamp) {
      timestamp = data;
    } else if (data is Map) {
      timestamp = Timestamp(data['_seconds'], data['_nanoseconds']);
    }
    return timestamp?.toDate();
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(DateTime dateTime) {
    final timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(dateTime);
    return {
      '_seconds': timestamp.seconds,
      '_nanoseconds': timestamp.nanoseconds,
    };
  }
}
```

then mark your field of your model like that:

```
@TimestampConverter() DateTime createdAt
```

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, timestamps gets returned as plain Map when using Cloud functions. But if you use Firebase SDK it returns `Timestamp` object.
I use the following function to handle both cases:

```dart
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865272/1321917
DateTime dateTimeFromTimestamp(dynamic val) {
  Timestamp timestamp;
  if (val is Timestamp) {
    timestamp = val;
  } else if (val is Map) {
    timestamp = Timestamp(val['_seconds'], val['_nanoseconds']);
  }
  if (timestamp != null) {
    return timestamp.toDate();
  } else {
    print('Unable to parse Timestamp from $val');
    return null;
  }
}
```

Works perfectly with `json_annotation` lib:

```dart
  @JsonKey(
      fromJson: dateTimeFromTimestamp,
      toJson: dateTimeToTimestamp,
      nullable: true)
  final DateTime subscriptionExpiryDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrey's answer is pretty good. Here's a JS/ Typescript adaptation, wrapped in a class:

```
import app from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

import TimeAgo from 'javascript-time-ago'
// Load locale-specific relative date/time formatting rules.
import en from 'javascript-time-ago/locale/en'

// Add locale-specific relative date/time formatting rules.
TimeAgo.addLocale(en)

// Adapted from Andrey Gordeev's answer at: 
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56245156/timestamp-from-firestore-gets-converted-to-a-map-when-using-cloud-function

class MyClass {
    timeAgo: TimeAgo

    constructor() {
        this.timeAgo = new TimeAgo('en-US')
    }

    getTimeText = (timeObject: any) => {
        // Convert to time text once it's of type firestore.Timestamp
        const getTextFromTimestamp = (timestamp: app.firestore.Timestamp) => {
            return this.timeAgo.format(timestamp.toDate())

        }
        if (timeObject instanceof app.firestore.Timestamp) {
            // Check if Timestamp (accessed from client SDK)
            return getTextFromTimestamp(timeObject)
        } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(timeObject) === '[object Object]') {
            // Check if it's a Map
            const seconds = timeObject['_seconds']
            const nanoseconds = timeObject['_nanoseconds']
            if (seconds && nanoseconds) {
                const timestamp = new app.firestore.Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds)
                return getTextFromTimestamp(timestamp)
            }
        }
        console.log('Couldn\'t parse time', timeObject)
        // Fallback
        return 'some time ago'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime? dateTimeFromTimeStamp(dynamic data) {
  Timestamp? timestamp;

  if (data is Timestamp) {
    timestamp = data;
  } else if (data is Map) {
    timestamp = Timestamp(data['_seconds'], data['_nanoseconds']);
  }
  return timestamp?.toDate();
}

Map<String, dynamic>? dateTimeToTimeStamp(DateTime? dateTime) {
  final timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(dateTime ?? DateTime.now());
  return {
    '_seconds': timestamp.seconds,
    '_nanoseconds': timestamp.nanoseconds,
  };
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
  @JsonKey(
      name: "creation_date",
      fromJson: dateTimeFromTimeStamp,
      toJson: dateTimeToTimeStamp)
  DateTime? creationDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by sending my timestamp as a String.

```dart
"timestamp": DateTime.now().toString()
```

Since now my timestamp is in string now so I get the exact timestamp from JSON as a String.
Now what I did was used a flutter plugin called `timeago` to convert it to time ago format for example: "10 mins ago"

```dart
Text(timeago.format(DateTime.parse(timestamp)).toString);
```

Comment: I don't recommend storing dates as strings in Firestore (or any other database, for that matter.  You should stick to the Timestamp, or if that doesn't work, use a single integer measured in unix epoch time.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question because I was trying to figure out why my cloud function wasn't properly parsing the Timestamp (and returning it to the caller). Indeed when logging, I noticed that my date field was being shown as `Timestamp { _seconds: N, _nanoseconds: NN }`

The solution was to simply cast the necessary field to a Timestamp class, before using it. Failing to do so would've returned the map instead:

```
const date = <field> as admin.firestore.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(expiryObj); //{_nanoseconds: 748000000, _seconds: 1612641862}

Timestamp tempstamp = Timestamp(expiryObj['_seconds'], expiryObj['_nanoseconds']);
DateTime expiryDateTime = tempstamp.toDate();

print(expiryDateTime); //2021-02-06 15:04:22.748
```

(import import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';)